# Does WSO2 Application Server's Throttling Function support username integration and multi-domain sharing?

Tags: wso2

As i was studying about WSAS (WSO2 Web Application Server) by follwing the 
link (http://wso2.com/library/articles/wso2-throttling/ 
 , I became very 
curious about the throttling method.

I believe that I understand the above link. However, I want to ask you if 
WSAS throttling... 
1) supports as a combination of SOAP operation + username unit 
    - I saw that WSAS has username/password, so I want to control 
throttling volume as API user unit by using username value.

2) is operated in multi-domain environment. Please check the below link. 
This is my full question 
    - 
http://wso2-oxygen-tank.10903.n7.nabble.com/Issue-WSO2-Appication-Server-Distributed-Throttling-is-now-working-td93044.html<https://email.accenture.com/owa/redir.aspx?C=0K45fzdVI06vfAqtym8Bpj-smFqyDNEIY5I3dT9GxXReOLvTwvoioNeKBpYaPf7SooUpayqIm8Q.&URL=http%3a%2f%2fwso2-oxygen-tank.10903.n7.nabble.com%2fIssue-WSO2-Appication-Server-Distributed-Throttling-is-now-working-td93044.html>